# How to copy data into a different collection for re-use in MarkLogic?

Tags: marklogic

I want to perform several operations on my existing data of `Database-A` and `Collection-1`. Once I perform all the operations I will lose my original data, as the data will get replaced by new data.

I want to create copy of my entire data in a different collection `Collection-B` into the same database `Database-A` or a different database `Test`, so that at a later stage I will not lose my existing data.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Documents are uniquely identified by the Database and URI.

Collections do not copy documents.

If you want to preserve stages of processing, it is more efficient 
and less error prone to write the new data to a different URI or Database ( URI is easier ), rather than copy the old data and then write new data ( 1 doc write vs 2, no copies needed and safer as no documents get overwritten ).

Either approach, using a URI "sub directory" hierarchy is a simple and common approach.

e.g.

- /docs/original/.../name
- /docs/stage1/.../name
- /docs/stageN/.../name

This is flexible over many stages.

If you use separate databases there is better isolation, but requires you to configure a new database for each stage, and manage permissions, indexes, etc.

The online docs gave good examples on [how to copy documents](https://developer.marklogic.com/recipe/move-a-document) if you decide to copy instead of writing to a new database.

Comment: @DALDEI-- Thanks for answering. Will this approach work if i am having several thousands documents in my DB ? Also, I want to run it through XQuery instead of JavaScript.

Comment: @Shalini Yes it will work, assuming your system has the appropriate resources.

Comment: I have a similar requirement and need to copy about 200+ million JSON files to another collection. Any ideas on how to do that?